# How do I cross-correlate timestamps?

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

Cross-correlation compares the correlation between two time series at different time lags.  Normally, this is done when the time series are represented as time series, i.e. vectors of signal magnitude at each point in time.  For example [Matlab's xcorr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) accepts time series vectors, whose length represents the total amount of time of the time series.  E.g.,

```
x = [1.1 1.2 1.9 1.6]
y = [2.1 2.2 -1.2 -1.5]
```

would be two time series.  `x` would encode that the value of `x` was 1.1 at time1, 1.2 at time2, etc., whereas `y` would encode that the value of `y` was 2.1 at time1, 2.2 at time2, etc.

What if you have timestamped events instead of a time series?  So you have a vector of event times, whose length is the number of events observed instead of the total length of time over which it was recorded.  For example, if you have the timestamps of tweets generated by two twitter feeds.  E.g.,

```
x = [1.213 2.200 2.303 10.259]
y = [1.1 3.39 20.38]
```

would be two vectors, `x` encoding that four `x` events occurred at t=1.213 sec, 2.200 sec, 2.303 sec, and 10.259 sec, whereas only three `y` events occurred, at t = 1.1 sec, 3.39 sec, and 20.38 sec.

I know that you could use the timestamps to generate very long binary time series with 0 everywhere except at the times that the timestamps correspond to.  This seems incredibly inefficient in terms of memory and prematurely reduces your temporal precision because precise timestamps must be converted into imprecise time bins.

Is there a built in Matlab function for doing such a cross correlation?

Comment: So, there's one row per event with each field or column capturing the sequential time of the event? If so, convert that into a multi-row, "stacked" data table where each row is an event with a time for that event.

Comment: no, it is a single dimension vector with a list of times at which events occurred. see question for clarification.

Comment: A couple of points should be made: first, this site is not intended to be a resource for software specific questions. This means that I am not obligated to provide you with details about Matlab functions. It also means that the onus is on you to work through any suggestions and make them compatible with your software of choice. Next, it would help potential respondents if you were to clarify why the *x* and *y* vectors aren't synchronized. In other words, what is the nature of these otherwise completely opaque events? Is *x* some kind of response to *y*?

Comment: Do your events have any associated "magnitude" data? Or are all events the same? From your current description, your data could be described as (very) sparse boolean time series. For example if you make some background time grid $t=t_{min}:\Delta t:t_{max}$, you could create time series of your first type using hist() in Matlab. However you might want to move your question to the [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: very sparse boolean time series!  that sounds exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First calculate the temporal distance between each event in `x` and each event in `y`.  Now you have a list of temporal distances (`diffs` in example below).  If you bin those temporal distances (with `histogram` for instance), you can see the cross-correlation between the two time series.

```
function diffs = xcorrTimestamps(x, y)
diffs = [];
for i = 1:length(x)
    diffs = [diffs, y-x(i)];
end
histogram(diffs)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of summarizing the relationships between time series that don't require precise synchronization. @Honi suggests one. This paper, *Recurrence Plots of Dynamical Systems* by Eckmann, Kamphorst and Ruelle (Europhys. Lett., 4, 91, pp. 973-977, 1987) discusses some others as well as proposing their own method.

Here is the abstract:

> A new graphical tool for measuring the time constancy of dynamical
>   systems is presented and illustrated with typical examples. In recent
>   years a number of methods have been devised to compute dynamical
>   parameters from time series. Such parameters are the information
>   dimension, entropy, Liapunov exponents, dimension spectrum, etc. In
>   all cases it is assumed that the time series is obtained from an
>   autonomous dynamical system, i.e. *the evolution equations do not
>   contain the time explicitly* (emphasis added). It is also assumed that
>   the time series is much longer than the characteristic times of the
>   dynamical system. In the present letter we present a new diagnostic
>   tool which we call *recurrence plot*; this tool tests the above
>   assumptions, and gives useful information also when they are not
>   satisfied. As the examples will show, the information obtained from
>   recurrence plots is often surprising, and not easily obtainable by
>   other methods.

And for an application of this approach, see Sornette and Zhou's paper *Non-parametric Determination of Real-Time Lag Structure between Two Time Series: the “Optimal Thermal Causal Path” Method* (http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0408166v1).